# JVM field descriptor for array of multiple types

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, signature, jvm-bytecode

I am looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2
and i am wondering how does one display the correct form of a method that takes in 2 different types.

E.g.

```
callthismethod(String a, ArrayMap<String aa, Task<String aaa> > )
```

where Task is imported from com.this.location

> The field descriptor of an instance variable of type `int` is simply `I`.
>
> The field descriptor of an instance variable of type `Object` is `Ljava/lang/Object;`. Note that the internal form of the binary name for class `Object` is used.
>
> The field descriptor of an instance variable that is a multidimensional `double` array, `double d[][][]`, is `[[[D`.

Comment: Thank you, now could you possibly explain your question in greater detail and clarity?

Comment: For e.g.,  a string would be Ljava.lang.String, but how would i represent the above argument in jvm form. 

[Ljava.lang.String;Lcom.this.location ?

Comment: Are you asking how something appears in a .class file?

Comment: I've not heard of "JVM form" although I've seen these descriptors in toString representation from objects that have not overridden Object's toString. Where would you use such a form?

Comment: yes perhaps my phrasing is incorrect. but i would like to see how it looks like. i have added an image into the post from jvm field descriptors.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion as you’re looking at a *field* descriptor but asking a question about a *method*. So you have to look at the [*method* descriptor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3) just beneath the “Field Descriptors” section.

A method descriptor has the form

> `(` ParameterDescriptor* `)` ReturnDescriptor

where the parameter descriptors have the same form as field descriptors, concatenated without any separators and the return descriptor only differs from field descriptors in also allowing `V`, to denote a `void` method.

Since your question doesn’t include the return type, and also doesn’t show the qualified name of the second parameter¹ (we might assume the first one is `java.lang.String`), no complete answer can be given for this example. If the method has been declared like

```java
void callthismethod(java.lang.String a, some.location.ArrayMap<String, Task<String>> aa)
```

the method descriptor would look like

```
(Ljava/lang/String;Lsome/location/ArrayMap;)V
```

Note that neither, field descriptors nor method descriptors, encode type arguments. [Generic signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.4) are an entirely different thing, only used for Reflection and debugging, not for the normal execution of code.

Getting the generic signature for your example is as problematic as getting the method descriptor, due to the missing information. Further, `com.this.location` is not a valid package name. Assuming `some.location` for `Task` as well, the generic signature would look like

```
(Ljava/lang/String;Lsome/location/ArrayMap<Ljava/lang/String;Lsome/location/Task<Ljava/lang/String;>;>;)V
```

---

¹ in fact, your declaration is entirely invalid as it tries to assign names to type arguments but not to the actual parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are no arrays, and type erasure means generics don't matter.  So this is just `Ljava/lang/String;Lwhatever/package/ArrayMap;`.  `Task` doesn't show up at all.